# Regarding Proof by Induction in Lemma 2.2.3 of Analysis 1 by Terence Tao

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction

https://math.unm.edu/~crisp/courses/math401/tao.pdf

Page 25, Lemma 2.2.3

The proof is done by showing Induction on n, $\textbf{keeping m fixed}$.

This means that this proof is valid for only that particular value of **m**.

But the Lemma claims for **any** natural number m.

This means that something is missing in my logic.

So does that fact that there was nothing special in the choice of **m** prove that it holds for any natural number **m**? But how do we write that Rigorously??

Comment: Was $m$ fixed but arbitrary?  If so, it's no different than proving $x^2 \geq 0$ for real $x$ by fixing an arbitrary $x$ and then proving it.

Comment: @Snmohith Raju : If Tao is not rigorous enough for you, then I suggest you start with $m=1$ and prove it, then go to $m=2$ and prove it, and so on.

Comment: Is any specific property of $m$ used? Of course not, because $m$ is just supposed to be a natural number. Hence the proof works for *every* $m$.